# Inserting column(s) into a python pandas dataframe in between other columns using the other column's names as the location?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file that I've converted into a dataframe. I would like to insert a column (or two depending on the situation) in between other columns.

For example:
I have columns:
Table-Chair-Bed

I want to insert column grass and column water in between Chair and Bed. I have tried:

```
df.insert(loc=2, column='grass', value='')
df.insert(loc=3, column='water', value='')
```

This does work but what if the columns change from the data source some of the time and the columns are like this: Couch-Kitchen-Table-Chair-Bed

I still want to insert these new columns in between Chair and Bed but don't want to have to re-write the code every time (because...automation). Is there a way to have the code look for the column names and insert the new columns in between them without using the location number, that way the column order or number of columns won't matter.

Comment: `df.insert(loc, column, value)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the position of the 'Chair' column and then add them after that.

```
df.insert(df.columns.get_loc('Chair') + 1, column='grass', value='')
```

Comment: Thank you for answering such a newbie question!

Answer (score 1):

```
cLoc1 = df.columns.get_loc("Chair")
cLoc2 = df.columns.get_loc("Bed")
df.insert(loc=cLoc1, column='grass', value='')
df.insert(loc=cLoc2, column='water', value='')
```

Basically, you get the location of the column you are looking for and then pass it on to your code.